# what could be cause of my slow running laptop on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, performance, task-manager

I am having a laptop which has 12 GB of RAM. 
Intel Core i3-60060 CPU 2 Ghz
it has become extremely difficult  to use this laptop for some unknown reason.
I am attaching a couple of screenshots which I could capture please see and help me to understand what can I disable so that I can use this efficiently or else I have plans to format this machine completely and put Ubuntu on it if nothing works. This is my last try with windows due to documentation purposes I have to use Microsoft office and a few software which I find difficult to work in Linux like Psiphon I am still using Windows 10 on it.

Taskmanager screenshots 
[image: running processes1]
[image: running processes2]

msconfig screenshots
removed 
I read a guide [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/slow-running-windows-10-laptop-performance-issues/d16af958-4a91-4bf6-b9fc-70b78c8043d7?tm=1575448084571#Main)
What is the problem please let me understand.

**update1**
as per comment I am updating taskmanager column with memory in priority
[image: task manager with memory high]

**update2**
based on comments below I executed the dism commands

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup 
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

first command above took 1 hour to execute.
second command above took 3-4 hours to execute.
reboot no issues found/corrected

```
sfc /scannow > reboot
```

no issues found.
After reboot and a using for 1 day reboot and shutdown and restart.
I am posting screenshots of  resmon.exe

The first screenshot below I have selected threads column to show maximum to lower threads in output.
[image: resmon.exe 1] 
The second column is based on commits column in resmon.exe output i.e. highest or maximum number of commits at top and then in descending order. 
[image: resmon.exe 2]

this third screenshot below is sorted on basis of CPU column of resmon.exe that is the highest CPU utilization at the top.
[image: resmon.exe 3]

I opened this question on microsoft answers website also
so giving some useful links which I got from there should help at later date someone who comes here
1)https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/slow-running-windows-10-laptop-performance-issues/d16af958-4a91-4bf6-b9fc-70b78c8043d7
2)https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-performance-and-install-integrity/75529fd4-fac7-4653-893a-dd8cd4b4db00

**update 3**
I scanned with advanced system care https://download.cnet.com/Advanced-SystemCare-Free/3055-2086_4-10407614.html  here are the logs https://pastebin.com/zJF2iix3
I am still debugging it will try Ubuntu from Live USB stick and post results here.
 I will follow it and post results here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft Edge is taking most of the resources, but before concluding on that, you might be having malware which is running in the background and consuming most of the resources.

Try running the malware scan.

Hope It helps,

Comment: there is no malware in system I added question with screenshots of resmon.exe probably this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do before you reinstall Windows 10 is to rule out the obvious possible causes of malware and hardware issue(s). That leaves a software issue in Windows 10 for you to focus on. Download the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso file and put it on a USB flash drive with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). Rufus is a utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives, such as USB keys/thumb drives, memory sticks, etc.

[image: Rufus]

Boot the Ubuntu 18.04 live USB and select the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option from the boot menu to run Ubuntu 18.04 as a live session. If Ubuntu runs properly in a live session, this is a sign that your laptop is running too slowly because of a software problem in Windows 10. Please comment about the results of running Ubuntu 18.04 as a live session for additional help troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I see in those screenshots is a lot of disk IO usage, I am sure that is where the problem is, since you have not maxed out the ram or processor.

Also since the processor seems to be running at max speed it is probably not a processor cooling issue.

My suggestion is to disable search indexing, uninstall all AVG software, and disable the windows update service (temporarily), and see if there is a noticeable change.
After they are all off also regularly check IO using resource monitor.

I would also do SMART checks on the disk, see if there is some obvious abnormalities that could cause performance issues, such as seek errors or read errors.