# 8 Gb pen drive does not show space when formatting with diskpart

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, diskpart, cleaning

I have a 8 GB usb and due to some problem 
as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1508614/)
I am trying to format my USB disk which is 8 GB in size. When I insert the USB following message pops up
[image: error message accessing USB]

so I decided to format the usb as per a tutorial [here](https://technastic.com/format-usb-drive-on-windows-10-using-command-prompt/)

when I execute command create partition primary it gives me the 
following error
[image: diskpart error1]
[image: DISKPART create partition primary]
[image: diskmgmt screenshot]
Now what should I do next?

Comment: Have you actually made a bootable Ubuntu USB installer with that? If so you need to recover it for usage as a normal mass storage device (assuming it isn't defective). This -> https://www.ampercent.com/recover-lost-space-removable-usb-drive/9352/ may give you clues about how to do it. It's not the same as formatting a single-partition typical mass storage device. If using Ubuntu, even from a live session (different USB stick though), MKUSB can be used for that in a very easy way.

Comment: Can you paste in a screenshot of your Disk Management window? That's the first place you should look when you notice something off with the reported size of a drive. Keyboard shortcut to get there: `Windows + X, K`.

Comment: @MrEthernet here is how it looks like in diskmgmt.msc https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aah5B_Tqrk7sT57MRs2EsCaswZwOBrCG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have got partial success I tried AOMEI partition assistant professional wizard since there are a lot of screenshots which will be difficult for me to paste here so I am giving a link to forum post where I discussed it https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/146540-formatting-pen-drive-diskpart.html#post1795092 however it is now showing 8 Gb space in diskpart output see this screenshot https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/drivers-hardware/259594d1576592412-formatting-pen-drive-diskpart-annotation-2019-12-17-180245.jpg 1 Mb is missing just. So I think if we try more it may work I am trying

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install 3rd party software, try [MiniTool Partition Manager](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).  Its free, easy to use, and works very well.  It deals with partitions that Windows doesnt handle easily.

The current installer will ask you to install other software, such as its shadow backup utility and some McAfee product, which you can safely uncheck.

Comment: I have tried a third party tool called AOMEI Partition manager some partial success has happened not full. 8 GB space has recovered but USB is not being detected by the Windows explorer screenshots are a lof in number so unable to post here giving a link to where I discussed this with all screenshots https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/8-gb-pen-drive-does-not-show-space-in-diskpart-can/43f28e41-9cf1-414f-89af-41d4f1a87732?tm=1576456712238&rtAction=1576593727522

Comment: I tried the free version of your tool. After scanning some thing happened but did not helped fully.At some stage it asked me to get a paid version. But thanks for your information as I tried some thing new.As mentioned in above comment I scanned with AOMEI and was able to recover partition only thing was that windows was not recognizing it so I tried some more things in diskpart and it worked since there are a lot of screenshots so I posted here https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/146540-formatting-pen-drive-diskpart-2.html#post1795181 so my problem is solved now.